# Boolean logic not working in array formula created with vba

Tags: excel, vba, boolean, array-formulas

I have a line of code in a vba script that creates an array formula in a column:

```
.Range(Cells(2, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1), Cells( _
    .UsedRange.Rows.Count, .UsedRange.Columns.Count + 1)) _
    .FormulaArray = "=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(FIND(tblDescriptionFilters" & _
    "[Description Filters], OFFSET($D$2, SUM(ROW())-2, 0)), 0))>0"
```

Example formula with values:

```
{=SUMPRODUCT( _
IFERROR(FIND({"DS","DISCO","DOTCOM"}, "[Redacted Stuff]DS [Redacted Stuff]"), 0))>0}
```

(Interestingly enough, when I use vba to input the values formula, it evaluates correctly).

The problem is that the formula is always returning false, even when it shouldn't. Case in point, by using the formula evaluation tool I observed an instance in which 4>0 returned false. When I used the fill handle to copy the formula into the adjacent column, the formula evaluates correctly (ie 4>0 returns true).

Besides that the one column was entered with vba, the only discernible difference is that when I try to make changes to one of the formulas in the vba range, I get the error message "You can't change part of an array."

I'm using Excel 2016.

Comment: I'd suggest that before implementing this formula is VBA, you get it working on the worksheet. (`=SUMPRODUCT(IFERROR(FIND(tblDescriptionFilters[Description Filters], OFFSET($D$2, SUM(ROW())-2, 0)), 0))>0`)  Since it's not being changed in any way by VBA it should work as-is on the worksheet, which is does not. One issue, `IFERROR` does not have a "value if error". (Maybe your brackets aren't lined up properly?)

Comment: When I first developed it, I developed it in the worksheet first, then implemented it with vba. Also as I mentioned, when I use the fill handle to duplicate the formula in the adjacent column, it works perfectly.

Comment: If the formula doesn't work even without VBA (directly on the worksheet) then [tag:vba] isn't the issue ,and this is an [tag:excel-formula] question, right? (So the question is tagged incorrectly). In order to help with the formula, it would be helpful to see some sample data... but the first step should be *simplifying* the formula. For example, get just the `FIND` portion working first.

Comment: ... But I just said the formula works perfectly when I duplicate/fill handle/copy & paste the formula from the column generated by vba into an adjacent column.

Comment: I've added a values only version for the formula. As I've pointed out, when generated by vba it will evaluate correctly. I will work on creating a jpg that shows the formula evaluation for both the vba and non vba formulas to demonstrate I'm not crazy.

Comment: One thing that will cause problems if you're not putting the VBA formula onto the activesheet is that `.Range` and `.UsedRange` is looking at the sheet referenced in the `With` statement, but `Cells` is only looking at the activesheet (there's no `.`).